# Plotting $e^{i (x+y)}+e^{i (x+z)}+e^{i (z+y)}$ for x,y,z are real

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to plot on the complex plane the values of  $e^{i (x+y)}+e^{i (x+z)}+e^{i (z+y)}$ for x,y,z are real.

For example for $x=y=0$, we get a $1+2\cos(z)+i2\sin(z)$ i.e. a circle of radius 2 center at $1+i0$.

1)Then how about with more variables? Any ways to go about it. I can't afford mathematica.

2)Will it cover the entire 3-disk (even though in a complicated way)?

3)Fixing $x=0$, we get $e^{iy}+e^{iz}+e^{i(y+z)}$. So as we vary z we get  circles of radius $r_{z}:=(1+e^{iz})$ rotating around the origin with centers on 1-circle ($e^{iz}$). At $z=\pi$ we just get point -1.

Thank you

Comment: If $x=0,y=\pi/2$ you have $i+(1+i)e^{iz}$ which is a circle of radius $\sqrt{2}$ centred at $i$

Comment: yeah I know but I am hoping for a quicker way than sampling. Maybe there is some conformal transformation that makes it obvious.

Comment: What kind of result are you hoping to get? One might note that a change of variables can get you to $e^{ia}+e^{ib}+e^{ic}$ meaning the output is the sum of three positions on a circle. This can at least tell you that the image of this expression is a closed disk of radius $3$.

Comment: I was hoping for someone with mathematica to plot it. I am not even sure, if the entire closed 3-disk will be covered or not because of their correlation. So they might be some blank areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$The image of the mapping $f:\Reals^{3} \to \Cpx$ defined by
$$
f(x, y, z) = e^{i(x + y)} + e^{i(x + z)} + e^{i(y + z)}
$$
is the closed disk of radius $3$ centered at $0$.

[image: The image of a sum of three complex exponentials]

To prove this, note that:

- The image of $f$ is invariant under rotations about $0$: If $\theta$ is real, then
  $$
  f(x + \tfrac{1}{2}\theta, y + \tfrac{1}{2}\theta, z + \tfrac{1}{2}\theta)
    = e^{i\theta}\, f(x, y, z).
  $$
- Fixing two variables gives, for example,
  $$
  f(x_{0}, y_{0}, z) = e^{i(x_{0} + y_{0})} + (e^{ix_{0}} + e^{iy_{0}}) e^{iz},
  $$
  which parametrizes the circle of radius $|(e^{ix_{0}} + e^{iy_{0}})|$ centered at $e^{i(x_{0} + y_{0})}$. If $y_{0} = -x_{0}$ in addition, we have
  $$
  f(x_{0}, -x_{0}, z) = 1 + (e^{ix_{0}} + e^{-ix_{0}}) e^{iz}
    = 1 + 2(\cos x_{0}) e^{iz}.
  $$
  The radius takes every value between $0$ and $2$ (inclusive), so the image of $f$ contains the interval $[0, 3]$ on the real axis.

By rotation invariance, the image contains the closed disk of radius $3$.

By the triangle inequality, the image is *contained in* the closed disk of radius $3$.

Comment: That is so beautiful.

Comment: In case it's of interest, the appearance of the image of a cubic grid (particularly, the order of rotational symmetry) varies depending on the number of subdivisions; the plot shows the cube $[-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi, \pi] \times [-\pi, \pi]$ divided into $20$ subintervals in each coordinate.